# WebImage crop not working as expected in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Asp.net mvc 4 to make a website where user can crop the image before uploading but for some reason it's not cropping. Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AdminProfilePic(HttpPostedFileBase file, int Top, int Left, int Bottom, int Right)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            string picName = User.Identity.Name;
            WebImage img = new WebImage(file.InputStream);
            string picExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            if (picExt == ".jpg" || picExt == ".gif" || picExt == ".jpeg" || picExt == ".png")
            {
                picExt = "PNG";
                string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Owners/"), picName);
               
                img.Crop(Top, Left, Bottom, Right);
                img.Save(path, picExt);
                TempData["pp_success"] = "Your profile picture has been updated successfully!";
                return RedirectToAction("AdminProfilePic");
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["pp_fail"] = "Error! Please upload a valid image file only!";
                return RedirectToAction("AdminProfilePic");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["pp_fail"] = "Error! No File was selected!";
            return RedirectToAction("AdminProfilePic");
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AdminProfilePic", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Error! Please provide valid information!")

    <input type="file" name="file" id="file01" style="width: 100%;" /><br />

    <img id="blah01" src="#" alt="your image" /><div id="cropper"></div>
    @Html.TextBox("Top", null, new { id = "Top" })<br />
    @Html.TextBox("Left", null, new { id = "Left" })<br />
    @Html.TextBox("Bottom", null, new { id = "Bottom" })<br />
    @Html.TextBox("Right", null, new { id = "Right" })<br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Update Profile Picture" />
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var img_left = 0;
    var img_top = 0;
    
    $("#blah01").load(function () {
        var imgCor = $("#blah01").position();
        img_left = imgCor.left;
        img_top = imgCor.top;
    });
    $("#cropper").draggable({
        containment: "#blah01", scroll: false,
        stop: function () {
            var getCor = $("#cropper").position();
            $("#Top").val(getCor.top - img_top);
            $("#Left").val(getCor.left - img_left);
            $("#Bottom").val(getCor.top - img_top + 200);
            $("#Right").val(getCor.left - img_left + 160);
        }
    });
});
```

Is there something wrong in my code? How can I crop the image using `WebImage Crop()` function by the given values in textboxes?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I don't get any error. Instead of cropping, it's uploading the whole image. It should be cropped according to the textbox values, then upload the cropped image.

Comment: Nope, According to your code, I believe the view is uploading the whole image and then at server your are cropping the image based on the size of crop

Comment: What I tried is, I passed the textbox values as parameters so that I can crop the image using those values, then upload it to the server. Maybe my code is wrong. If you think my code is wrong, then please provide me the correct code. It'll be really helpful for me.

Comment: Your View should have some JavaScript. What are you getting the values of Top, Bottom, Left & Right when you debug the code after cropping?

Comment: Please check my updated post. I've provided the `JS` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake At this point:

```
img.Crop(Top, Left, Bottom, Right);
img.Save(path, picExt);
```

The Method Crop returns a `WebImage` object which you have not collected. That Object is the cropped image. So make this small change:

```
var img_cropped=img.Crop(Top, Left, Bottom, Right);
img_cropped.Save(path, picExt);
```

This Should do it.

The Java script here is having problem

```
$("#Bottom").val(getCor.top - img_top + 200);
$("#Right").val(getCor.left - img_left + 160);
```

Its just adding 200px to top and 160px to left. Its just static. You can just pass plain integral values in the bottom and right textboxes to test. The C# Code is working. I checked it.

Comment: Can you please debug and let me know what values you are getting for top, left, bottom and right?

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same value from the text boxes like `7, 355, 207, 515` etc.

Comment: May I know what is the original size of image you are cropping?

Comment: Original size is, 600px x 600px

Comment: Okay So I guess the values you are getting is way too much. For Example, if you crop 355px from left and 515px from right the image will be of negative width. which is not possible. So problem in javascript which is calculating the crop size

Comment: Probably, but how can it be fixed then?

Comment: I've updated the answer. The problem is the javascript. Please go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage.crop(v=vs.111).aspx to see how crop works.